# I want to add a new sheet in an excel created using .to_excel in pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

This is my code, how do I add another data frame to the same excel, say: 'df3', but on a different sheet:

```
df2.to_excel('Invoicing Detail Output File.xlsx', index = False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write directly to a new excel ([see](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html)):

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('Invoicing Detail Output File.xlsx') as writer:
    df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
    df3.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet2')
```

Or append to existing excel:

```
with ExcelWriter('Invoicing Detail Output File.xlsx', mode='a') as writer:
    df3.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet2')
```